# how to send APDU commands in android

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce, secure-element

i want to send APDU commands from my android device and also receive it in same device. is it possible ?

i want to get response in following mthod

```
@Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received APDU: " + ByteArrayToHexString(commandApdu));

    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Send APDUs between two Android devices?

Comment: not between two , is possible in one devices?

Comment: So you want to send APDU commands from one app to another app on the same device? Why would you want to do that? Are you sure that NFC/APDUs (which is typically used for communication between two devices) is the right approach for your usage scenario?

Comment: yes sure.. i need that

Comment: Once again: Why would you want to do that? What is your usage scenario?